# Create task in grunt in another file

Tags: gruntjs

I wrote simple task in Grunt. Now, I would like to export this task to another file, and I have a problem with it.
How can I find file with my task? This task just searches string from website and putting it in the file. I'm trying load it by: `grunt.loadTasks('grunt-find');`
I have file (grunt-find) with find.js inside. But it doesn’t work... Can I have to add find.js somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grunt.loadTask()` will load every JS file in the directory provided as argument; so, basically, you have to do something like:

```
grunt.loadTasks("tasks");
```

and you may have a directory called "tasks":

```
project root
|- tasks
|--- file.js
|- Gruntfile.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find the "directory only" behavior of `grunt.loadTask()` annoying (i.e. want to keep external tasks definitions next to external task configuration), you can try something like that :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
  var _ = require('lodash');

  /*** External config & tasks filepaths ***/

  //we have 1 base config, and possibly many module-specific config
  var configLocations = ['./grunt-config/default_config.js', './grunt-config/**/config.js'];

  //we have 1 base tasks definition, and possibly many module-specific config
  var tasksLocations = ['./grunt-config/default_tasks.js', './grunt-config/**/tasks.js'];


  /* Typical project layout (matching with the globbing pattern above - adapt to your project structure) :

  ├── Gruntfile.js 
  ├── package.json
  ├── grunt-config
  │   ├── homepage
  │   │   └── config.js
  │   ├── navigation
  │   │   └── config.js
  │   ├── module1
  │   │   ├── config.js
  │   │   └── tasks.js
  │   ├── default_config.js
  │   ├── default_tasks.js
  │   └── template_module_grunt.txt
  ├── website_directory1
  │   ├── mdp
  │   ├── multimedia-storage
  │   ├── mv-commit.sh
  │   ├── query
  │   ├── temp
  │   └── tmp
  └── website_directory2
      ├── crossdomain.xml
      ├── css
      ├── favicon.ico
      ├── fonts
      :
      :
      :

  */

  /***************** External configuration management ***********************************/

  var configFiles = grunt.file.expand({
    filter: "isFile"
  }, configLocations );

  grunt.log.writeln('Gathering external configuration files'.underline.green);
  grunt.log.writeln("configFiles : " + grunt.log.wordlist(configFiles, {
    separator: ', ',
    color: 'cyan'
  }));

  var configArray = configFiles.map(function(file) {
    grunt.log.writeln("=> importing : " + file);
    return require(file)(grunt, env);
  });

  var config = {};

  configArray.forEach(function(element) {
    config = _.merge(config, element);
  });

  grunt.initConfig(config);

  /***************** Task loading & registering *******************************************/
  // We load grunt tasks listed in package.json file
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  /****** External tasks registering ****************/
  grunt.log.writeln('Gathering external task files'.underline.green);

  var taskFiles = grunt.file.expand({
    filter: "isFile"
  }, tasksLocations);

  grunt.log.writeln("task files : " + grunt.log.wordlist(taskFiles, {
    separator: ', ',
    color: 'cyan'
  }));

  taskFiles.forEach(function(path) {
    grunt.log.writeln("=> loading & registering : " + path);
    require(path)(grunt);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:gruntfile', 'logConfig']);

  grunt.registerTask('checkGruntFile', 'Default task - check the gruntfile', function() {
    grunt.log.subhead('* Tâche par défaut - aide et vérification du gruntfile *');
    grunt.log.writeln('Exécutez "grunt -h" pour avoir plus d\'informations sur les tâches disponibles');
    grunt.log.writeln('...');
    grunt.log.subhead('Vérification du gruntfile...');
    grunt.task.run(['jshint:gruntfile']);
  });

  //write the generated configuration (for debug)
  grunt.registerTask('logConfig', 'Write the generated conf', function() {
    //grunt.task.run(['attention:gruntfile']);
    grunt.log.subhead('* Configuration générée : *');
    grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(config, undefined, 2));
  });

};
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/0gust1/7683132